# What are the colored borders of a tatami called?

Tags: word-choice

I researched several dictionaries and I am unable to precisely identify the term. Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are called 「へり」 or 「畳{たたみ}（の）へり」.

The pitch accent is on the 「り」, which would mean that many J-learners would tend to pronounce the word incorrectly by placing the accent on the first syllable 「へ」.

It is 「[へり]{LH}」.

Put the accent on the 「へ」 and you will be saying the katakana word 「ヘリ」 meaning "**helicopter**" instead -- 「[ヘリ]{HL}」.

[image]

Comment: It's interesting that many japanese native speakers I speak to, complain that in english you sometimes change the pronunciation of a character, that it isnt't phonetic. But japanese itself also has it's own tricks when it comes to pronunciation, right?